# Google classroom show only tasks that are unfinished

Tags: google-api-js-client, google-classroom

I'm trying to build something with google classroom api.(vue-gapi)
Now i can list all tasks with this code

```
const gapi = await this.$gapi.getGapiClient()
        const response = await gapi.client.classroom.courses.courseWork.list({
            courseId: this.course.id,
            pageSize: 100,
        })
        const classworks = response.result.courseWork || [];
```

But i want to show only the tasks that the user hasn't turned in.
I can do this by looping through all the tasks and check for Studentsubmission like this

```
for(var i=0;i<tasks.length;i++){
            var currentTask = tasks[i]
        
        const gapi = await this.$gapi.getGapiClient()
        const response = await gapi.client.classroom.courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions.list(
            {userId:this.userId,
            courseId:this.currentTask.courseId,
            courseWorkId:this.currentTask.taskId
            }


        )
        
       
        var submission = response.result.studentSubmissions[0]
        console.log("response", response.result.studentSubmissions)
        }
```

But I think that are a lot of gapi requests and it makes everything slow.
So i suspect I'm doing it the wrong way.
Does anybody have a suggestion on doing it the right way?

Answer (score 1):

i figured it out...
Maybe it can be useful for others...
When you use "_" for courseWorkId, you get a list of all courseworksubmissions for the student.
So something like :

```
    const gapi = await this.$gapi.getGapiClient()
    const response = await gapi.client.classroom.courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions.list(
        {
           userId:this.userId,
           courseId:this.currentTask.courseId,
           courseWorkId:'_'
        }
    )
```